# How to check the Cortex-M4 VTOR register with gdb command?

Tags: arm, gdb, embedded, cortex-m, armv7

(I am learning about ARM debugging so this may be a dumb question.)

I checked the ARMv7-M Arch Ref Manual. It says the reset vector offset is stored in the VTOR (Vector Table Offset Register).

I am using a gdb specific to the Cortex-M. So I expected the gdb command `info registers` should show the `VTOR` register. But it only shows some general registers.

So is there a way to check VTOR with gdb command?

Thanks!

### ADD 1 - 7:43 AM 3/2/2022

The `VTOR` is memory mapped to `0xe000ed08` according to the ARMv7 ARM. But when I try to access it with gdb command, it shows below error:

```
>>> x /4xb 0xe000ed08
0xe000ed08:     Cannot access memory at address 0xe000ed08
```

And according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623111/arm-gdb-cannot-access-memory-only-on-linux), I checked the memory region known to the gdb client:

```
>>> info mem
Using memory regions provided by the target.
Num Enb Low Addr   High Addr  Attrs
0   y   0x00000000 0x00100000 flash blocksize 0x1000 nocache
1   y   0x10001000 0x10001400 flash blocksize 0x400 nocache
2   y   0x20000000 0x20040000 rw nocache
```

It seems the VOTR offset 0xe000ed08 is **not within these regions**.

Now I am looking into how to workaround this.

Not sure which decides it:

- Something I can configure?
- Or determined by the [reel board](https://www.phytec.eu/product-eu/internet-of-things/reelboard/) manufacturer?
- Or the binary I flashed into the board?

### ADD 2 - 4:46 PM 5/3/2022

A similar issue with `Cannot access memory at address xxxx` error. It may be related to optimization. But no definite answer yet.

https://github.com/adamgreen/gcc4mbed/issues/35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the missing region using the gdb [`mem` command.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Region-Attributes.html)

```
mem 0xE0000000 0xE00FFFFF
```

Then you will be able to access the VTOR at 0xe000ed08.

For a more permanent solution add the region to the target memory map configuration (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Map-Format.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is a memory mapped register, so you can inspect it that way.

Get the address from the manual you mention:

`0xE000ED08 VTOR RW 0x00000000a Vector Table Offset Register, VTOR on page B3-601.`

Try something like
`(gdb) x/w 0xe000ed08`

Comment: Thanks! I found the VTOR address. However, it shows "Cannont access memory at address 0xe000ed08". I updated my question with more details.

Comment: BTW, the VTOR address is listed in ARMv7 arch ref manual B3.2.2.

Comment: Sorry I can only mark one answer. Your reply is also very valuable. Thanks.